# Splitting Pig tuple

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to split the following tuple into two tuples using pig script.

```
 (key=bb7bde5661923b947ce59958773e85c5\,\/css\/bootstrap.min.cssHTTP\/1.1\,\/con-us.php,\/con-us.phpHTTP\/1.1\)
```

I want the output as follows:

```
(key=bb7bde5661923b947ce59958773e85c5\)     (\/css\/bootstrap.min.cssHTTP\/1.1\,\/con-us.php,\/con-us.phpHTTP\/1.1\)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can solve this problem using `REGEX and TOTUPLE` function. First split the string into two parts, first column is before the first comma and second column is remaining strings. Finally convert the two columns as tuples and store it.

**input**

```
key=bb7bde5661923b947ce59958773e85c5\,\/css\/bootstrap.min.cssHTTP\/1.1\,\/con-us.php,\/con-us.phpHTTP\/1.1\
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'^([^,]+),(.*)$')) AS (col1,col2);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE TOTUPLE(col1),TOTUPLE(col2);
STORE C INTO 'output';
```

**Output:**( will be stored in `output/part*` file)

```
(key=bb7bde5661923b947ce59958773e85c5\) (\/css\/bootstrap.min.cssHTTP\/1.1\,\/con-us.php,\/con-us.phpHTTP\/1.1\)
```